# Connect mosquitto as a publisher

Tags: authentication, authorization, mqtt, mosquitto

I have running mosquitto and I want to do that only one client can connect to topic as publisher (maybe with password or something) others can only conncet as subscriber.

Defining topic and user access rights at conf file is the way that. But in my application topics are created dynamically at run time.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: What have you already tried? The docs about how to set up a ACL are easy to find

Comment: Doc is clear. But I forgot to say topics are dynamically created. Therefore defining them on acl file is not practical I think

Comment: Edit the question to include some examples and what you've tried

Comment: I added the dynamically part. I will add some codes and conf file soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [mosquitto-auth-plug](https://github.com/jpmens/mosquitto-auth-plug)

> ... plugin can perform authentication (check username / password) and
>   authorization (ACL).

You may need to modify one of the backends suited for you if you want to have a dynamic behavior on topic authorization. See `be_jwt_aclcheck` functions.